# How to implement transparent transaction system (i.e: prisma.js)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, orm, transactions, prisma

In the [Prisma ORM docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/transactions#sequential-prisma-client-operations) we can find following example of grouping few DB calls in one transaction. I am wonder how the following could be implemented. Methods used in `$transactions()` (`prisma.post...`) are the same we can use "standalone".

```
const [posts, totalPosts] = await prisma.$transaction([
  prisma.post.findMany({ where: { title: { contains: 'prisma' } } }),
  prisma.post.count(),
])
```

I am wondering how it is possible to implement such an method (`$transation()`).
My only idea would be to check "context" (`this`) but not sure is it the cleanest idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I understand the question correctly.
Are you attempting to return the count of posts where the title contains the word "prisma"? If so, you should use [interactive transactions](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/transactions#interactive-transactions) API to achieve this.

```js
const [posts, totalPosts] = await prisma.$transaction(async (prisma) => {
    const posts = await prisma.post.findMany({
        where: {
            title: {
                contains: 'prisma'
            }
        }
    })
    const count = prisma.post.count({
        where: {
            title: {
                contains: 'prisma'
            }
        }
    })
    return [posts, count]
})
```

Comment: Sorry, it looks i forgot about the most crucial sentence here, I would like to see how the `$transaction()` method could be implemented.